# How filtering field(M2o) child by list in parent with XML

Tags: odoo-8

in XML, how i can use domain="[('field2','in',parent.field1)]"
like field1 is Many2one in parent class.
field2 is Many2one in child class. ?

Comment: one of the answers, domain="[('field2','in',[parent.field1])]", but this not work, help me please.

Comment: Give me Example for this concept.

Comment: my code python:

Comment: my code python:  
 demande_id = fields.Many2one('gmat.demande',string='N° Demande',required=True)          "I want load all values in lis_mat to class child codebarre"
 articles_ids = fields.One2many('gmat.articlemouv', 'arts_ids',string='Mouvement')
 lis_mat=fields.Many2many('gmat.nbien')
 @api.multi
 @api.onchange('demande_id')  def list_mouv(self):
{code func}
code class child :                                           arts_ids = fields.Many2one('gmat.mouvements',string='num')
 codebarre = fields.Many2one('gmat.nbien',